# bind but not display items in drop down in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a question here.

I want to bind a drop down in c# with below values

```
value    text
-----    ----
1         abc
2         pqr
3         xyz
4         ppp
```

however i want to display only items related to 1,2 and 3.

is it possible to bind all values however display not all items

Comment: Could you show your tried code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `Enabled = false` for the last ListItem object.  My advice would probably be to not even include that ListItem in the list of items you are binding too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list.DataSource = myDataSource;
list.DataBind();

list.Items.Remove(list.Items.FindByText("ppp"));
```

OR

```
list.Items.Remove(list.Items.FindByValue("4"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove from your DropDownList

```
ListItem itemToRemove = myDropDown.Items.FindByValue("4");
if (itemToRemove != null)
{
    myDropDown.Items.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
```

Comment: hello, i want to hide items not remove

Comment: I Suggest you to filter with DataView ? What do you  think

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

In your `DataTemplate`, just bind the visibility of your object to... your criteria (it seems to be the index ?) and include the Show/Hide logic inside a converter.

**EDIT** Something like this :

```
<DataTemplate>
  <ContentPresenter Visibility="{Binding Index, Converter={StaticRessource IndexTovisibilityConverter}}>
    // Here your datatemplate
  </ContentPresenter>
<Datatemplate>
```

And inside your converter :

```
public class IndexTovisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
{

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
     int index= (int)value;

      if (index > 3)
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
      else
        return Visibility.Visible;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure. Not an expert in asp but I'll try :-)
I'll edit my post in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

you could do it in code behind.

> ```
>     ListItem l = new ListItem();
>     l.Text = "New";
>     l.Value = "new";
>     l.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("visibility", "hidden");
> ```